# Live chat on website using QuickBlox API

Tags: quickblox

We want to develop website live chat widget using QuickBlox Chaa API.

1) In such widget user need not to login and just start chatting. Can we create one generic user that can be used for all chat sessions ?
2) Second requirement is store chat conversation , is there a way to store chat session there a way to get chat session text. Can we hook into it ?

Please tell us if its possible or not.

Answer (score 2):

1) You have to register on [quickblox.com](http://quickblox.com/). After that, create your project for an your application. Get tokens and keys to access your application. And you will have one primary user to work with QB and its modules.

2) You do not have to ask the user registration. Just give them names for a chat. If you want to use the source code of the widget [ChattAR](https://github.com/QuickBlox/ChattAR-ios), just remove the registration code. Allow the user to enter a user name by which he enters.

3) Keep the message history you can in a module ["Custom objects"](http://quickblox.com/developers/Custom_Objects). This module is a flexible tool, you can create any number of data fields, and select one for each type of data you need.
Also, you can save any files (text etc.) in ["Content"](http://quickblox.com/modules/content/) module for getting chat session text.